# How to solve Postgres 11 error : cannot route inserted tuples to a foreign table

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, foreign-data-wrapper

I am trying the partitioning and FDW example explained in https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-11-sharding.html. After creating the FDW extension and foreign partition table (`temperatures_2016`), when I try to insert 2016 data into the master table temperatures it throws

> ERROR:  cannot route inserted tuples to a foreign table.

How do I resolve this ?

-- on other server box2

```
CREATE TABLE temperatures_2016 (
    at      date,
    city    text,
    mintemp integer,
    maxtemp integer
);
```

--on my server

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE temperatures_2016
    PARTITION OF temperatures
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2016-01-01') TO ('2017-01-01')
    SERVER box2;

INSERT INTO temperatures (at, city, mintemp, maxtemp) 
VALUES ('2016-08-23', 'HongKong', 29, 40);
```

I expect the row to be inserted in the foreign partition table instead I get

> ERROR:  cannot route inserted tuples to a foreign table SQL state:
>   0A000

Answer (score 1):

You probably have PostgreSQL version 10.

Inserting into a table with partitions that are foreign tables has been [introduced in v11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-11.html):

> - Allow `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `COPY` on partitioned tables to properly route rows to foreign partitions (Etsuro Fujita, Amit Langote)
>
>   This is supported by `postgres_fdw` foreign tables.

At any rate, that error message does not appear in the v11 code base.

Perhaps you are connecting to a v10 server with a v11 client?

Comment: The version of postgre installed on my machine is PostgreSQL-11.1-1-win64-bigsql and pgAdmin 4.

Comment: You are right. I am using v10 server with a v11 client..On command line postgres -V show 11.1 ,  when I check the application services ,it shows PostgreSQL Server 10 to be running.Thank you Laurenz

Comment: You can simply `SHOW server_version;`.